# Why Dependency Injection doesn't know about my repo?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have a weird situation. I need to use Entity Framework 6.2 for my .net core app.

**An ordinary Controller**

```
public class SampleApiController : BaseController
{
   // use _repo and other stuff
}
```

**Base Controller**

```
public class BaseController : Controller
    {
        protected IRepo_repository;

        public BaseController(IRepo repository)
        {
            _repository = repository;
        }

        public BaseController() : this(null)
        {

        }
    }
```

**App DBContext**

```
public class SampleContext : DbContext
    {
        public SampleContext(string connectionString)
            :base(connectionString)
        {
            try
            {   
                this.Database.Log = (s) => System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(s);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //CurrentLogger.Log.Error(e);
            }
        }

        public DbSet<Test1> Test1s { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Test2> Test2s { get; set; }
    }
```

**Repository interface**

```
public interface IRepo
    {
// methods definition
}
```

**Repository class**

```
public interface Repo : IRepo
    {
// methods implementation
}
```

**Startup.cs -> ConfigureServices method**

```
services.AddScoped<SampleContext>((s) => new SampleContext(configuration["ConnectionStrings:SampleApp"]));
        services.AddScoped<IRepo, Repo>();
```

**In this picture you could see that repository param is empty... not initialized with Repo instance... (!!! In this picture IRepo is IRepositoryBase)**

[image]

**Solution !**

As CodeNotFound and Riscie said in comments, the problem was that BaseController was initialized with null... Thanks guys!

Comment: your Repo does not implement the IRepo interface

Comment: Repo is an interface .. it should be class and implement IRepo

Comment: What is the purpose of having a default constrcutor here? I think the DI take the default stor which call `this(null)` Tha is where you get the `null` value. Put a breakpoint there and test.

Comment: The only service you've registered is `IRepo => Repo`, but you're injecting `IRepositoryBase`. You haven't told the DI container how to handle `IRepositoryBase`.

Comment: FWIW, *don't use the repository pattern*. The repository pattern is for working with something low-level like SQL. An ORM, like Entity Framework, *already* implements the repository pattern. That's what your `DbSet`s are. Wrapping that in a repository is just a useless abstraction that adds additional entropy to your code (more to maintain, more to test), with no benefit (you still have a dependency on EF either way).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Repository interface**

```
public interface IRepo
{
    // methods definition
}
```

**Repository class**
*I have changed this from interface to class and made it implement the IRepo Interface*

```
public class Repo : IRepo
{
    // methods implementation
}
```

**Edit:** *Also remove the second constructor*

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected IRepo_repository;

    public BaseController(IRepo repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    //second constructor most likely introduces the problem
}
```

Comment: sorry, I forgot to put that in this sample. In code it is.

Comment: in your `BaseController` constructor  (in the screenshot), you also instantiate `IRepositoryBase` instead of `IRepo`.

Comment: also, why do you have a constructor initializing your BaseController with null? (see my edit)

Answer (score 0):

You normally pass `IRepo` from `SampleApiController` to `BaseController`.

Base on my understanding, you do not need no argument constructor in `BaseController`. If so, you might want to remove it to prevent `_repository` being `null`.

```
public class SampleApiController : BaseController
{
    public SampleApiController(IRepo repository) 
        : base(repository)
    {
    }
}

public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected IRepo _repository;

    public BaseController(IRepo repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    /*public BaseController() : this(null)
    {    
    }*/
}

public interface IRepo
{
    // methods definition
}
```